# Word VBA - How to stop people from saving a form if they have not filled out required fields using DocumentBeforeSave?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm currently making a form and attempting to stop a person from perform a "save as" or "save" if not all required fields are filled. The example below is just one field for Engineer Name. The intention is that if the user doesn't fill out the Form Field in this case called "EngName" then the document will show an error message "Save Cancelled, Engineer Name Required". I think I'm close but don't know VBA and would appreciate any help.

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub Document_Open()
Set App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc as Document, SaveAsUI AS Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    With ActiveDocument.FormFields("EngPhone")
       If Len(.Results) < 1 Then Cancel = True
           MsgBox ("Save Cancelled, Engineer Name Required")
       End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Private Sub wdApp_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If Trim(ActiveDocument.FormFields("EngPhone").Result) = "" Then
  Cancel = True
  MsgBox ("Save Cancelled, Engineer Name Required")
End If
End Sub
```

You'll need to add the above code to a 'ThisApplication' class module and you'll still need your instantiating code, which goes in an ordinary code module. For more details, see: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/AppClassEvents.htm

Comment: When trying to save it with this in the Visual Basic and the field being empty in Restricted Editing it didn't stop me from saving but I'm not entirely positive if that's just because I'm simply not calling upon it properly in some way to trigger it

Comment: Okay got it. This is my first time finding out you could even code in Word so hopefully that direction will be enough to get me through this but we'll see. Regardless thank you

Comment: For more details, see: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/AppClassEvents.htm

Comment: I have never felt a greater feeling of euphoria. I spent 8 hours trying to figure that out thank you